# C# Singalr to receive data from backand servers

Tags: c#, signalr, cross-platform

I have a chat SignalR server, the chat support group chatting.
I also have a server which actually creates the groups and other group managment tools.

Whenever a user leaves a group (via http post ) to server, I want the chat service to trigger some methods, such as LeaveGroup and some other logictics.

I bound the connectionId to userId so I got the parsing request covered.

QUESTION IS: What is the best practice of communication between server/service and the signalr server.

Taking in mind, I dont want to compormise on scalability on each of my servers/services.

My idea is more or less host a web api server inside the SignalR server, but I can't seem to find any topics suggesting that could damage the performance.

Ideas? 
Thanks alot.

p.s

I know that there is no code involved in here. but it seems irrelevant. I have self hosted web api in a window service I have, so the code is pretty much the same.

**I would love to provide more data/information if thats neccesary**

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this documentation is most applicable to what you're trying to do: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr

It speaks specifically about how to communicate from your server/service application to the signalr clients. Communicating from the client to the server/service could be done either through the signalr hub, or with other web API.

From a best practice perspective, the documentation specifically states (https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub):

> If you need to use the context multiple-times in a long-lived object,
>   get the reference once and save it rather than getting it again each
>   time. Getting the context once ensures that SignalR sends messages to
>   clients in the same sequence in which your Hub methods make client
>   method invocations. For a tutorial that shows how to use the SignalR
>   context for a Hub, see Server Broadcast with ASP.NET SignalR.

If you're *really* into scalability, you might want to look into integrating your signalr communications into some other message queueing system, but that's probably overkill for most circumstances.

Comment: after reading it more and more, its really not what i was looking for.
I asked for a way to connect backend service with signalr. you just gave me the documnetation of how to create a signalr project.

Comment: Sorry. Let's see if I can get some clarification. Is your goal to communicate from the server through signalr to the client, or from the client, through signalr to the server?

Comment: From the server to the signalR server. I gave a really good example with the chat.
I have 2 server. 1 chat and 1 rest. The rest server can get a LeaveGroup request, this should result in updating the client state in the signalR server, aka - removing it from the Group.